# PHP search query with radio button

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

Am trying add to my search query a new statement which is plot-available (radio button value yes or no). Could you tell me if my way of thinking is right. Much appreciate.

Regards

```
if ( count( $_GET ) > 0 && isset( $_GET[ 'location' ] ) && isset( $_GET[ 'bedrooms' ] ) && isset( $_GET[ 'price' ] ) && isset($_GET[ 'plot_available' ]) == 'yes' ) {

                                    $location = $_GET[ 'location' ];
                                    $bedrooms = $_GET[ 'bedrooms' ];
                                    $price = $_GET[ 'price' ];
                                    $plot_available = $GET['plot_available'];
```

I have added isset($_GET[ 'plot_available' ] and search query dont work.

Update:

```
    <?php
                                if ( count( $_GET ) > 0 && isset( $_GET[ 'location' ] ) && isset( $_GET[ 'bedrooms' ] ) && isset( $_GET[ 'price' ] ) && isset($_GET[ 'plot_available' ]) && ($_GET['plot_available'] == 'yes') ) {

                                    $location = $_GET[ 'location' ];
                                    $bedrooms = $_GET[ 'bedrooms' ];
                                    $price = $_GET[ 'price' ];
                                    $plot_available = $GET['plot_available'];

                                    $args = array(
                                        'post_type' => 'development',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                        'location' => $location,
                                        'bedrooms' => $bedrooms,
                                        'price' => $price
                                    );
                                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                    if ( $query->found_posts < 1 ) {

                                        echo '<article><h2>No Results Found</h2>';
                                        echo '<p>No developments have been found for your search query. Please click <a href="' . get_home_url() . '">here</a> to return to the home page and try again with different search parameters.</p></article>';

                                    } else {

                                        echo '<ul id="posts" class="posts">';

                                            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                                                <li class="post clearfix">  
                                                    <?php
                                                        $loc_term = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'location' );
                                                        $bedroom_term = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'bedrooms' );
                                                        $price_term = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'price-range' );
                                                        $house_term = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'house-type' );

                                                        $link = get_term_link( $loc_term[0] ) . '#' . $post->post_title;

                                                        $loc_name = '';
                                                        if ( isset( $loc_term[0]->name ) ) {
                                                            $loc_name = ' - ' . $loc_term[0]->name;
                                                        }

                                                        echo '<h2><a href="' . $link . '">' . get_the_title() . $loc_name . '</a></h2>';
                                                        if ( isset( $bedroom_term[0] ) ) { echo '<p><strong>' . $bedroom_term[0]->name . '</strong></p>'; }
                                                        if ( isset( $price_term[0] ) ) { echo '<p><strong>' . $price_term[0]->name . '</strong></p>'; }
                                                        if ( isset( $house_term[0] ) ) { echo '<p><strong>' . $house_term[0]->name . '</strong></p>'; }
                                                    ?>
                                                </li>

                                        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();

                                        echo '</ul>';

                                    }

                                } else {

                                    echo '<article><h2>Invalid Search</h2>';
                                    echo '<p>Oops, something went wrong with your search. Please click <a href="' . get_home_url() . '">here</a> to return to the home page and try again.</p></article>';

                                }
                            ?>
```

I have to display only available plots.

Comment: You missed the '_' (underscore)....

Comment: `$GET` != `$_GET`. and `isset(...) == 'yes'` is useless. isset returns boolean true/false, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
isset($_GET[ 'plot_available' ]) == 'yes'
```

with this:

```
isset($_GET[ 'plot_available' ]) && ($_GET['plot_available'] == 'yes')
```

Comment: Can you paste the html form code here? Maybe you are missing out something

Comment: This is a wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use a tax_query to search by terms?
As I understand the situation, you need a tax_query.

Try this updated version of the `$args`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'development',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // not sure what is the case, could be OR
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $location
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bedrooms',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $bedrooms
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'price-range',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $price
        ),
    )
);
```

I am not sure about the values of `$location`, `$bedrooms` and `$price` so you might want to leave it as is if you are using slugs, or remove it if you are using id's (since the default is term_id).

Comment: The search query is working fine but i would like add to search query a statement plot_available. So if we have available property with searched criteria like bedroom price and location then property is displayed. Plot_available is a radio button with values yes or no

Comment: Am not to sure about that. am using a custom fields. i ve set plot_available to radio button.